# Detect type of vapor worker at runtime

Tags: swift, vapor

We have a Vapor API which uses a web worker, a queues worker and a scheduled queues worker. Every worker has the same `configure(_ app: Application)` function.

In this function, I'd like to find the type of the worker, rather it's the web or on of the queues worker.

```swift
// configures the worker
public func configure(_ app: Application) throws {
    // clear every middleware
    app.middleware = .init()

    // HERE I want to differentiate the worker
    if web worker {
        // do that
    } else {
        // do something other
    }
}
```

Is there a way or a method in the `Application` that tells me the type of it?

Our main problem is, that we want to `try app.autoMigrate().wait()`, but only on the web worker.

Currently all workers try to migrate the database and two of it fail, obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use environment variables to do this. Use something like this in your start-up:

```bash
WEBWORKER=1 /home/vapor/myapp/.build/release/Run serve --env production
```

Only run the migrations if the instance has the correct variable/value by putting this:

```swift
if let worker = Environment.get("WEBWORKER") {
    try app.autoMigrate().wait()
}
```

See [here](https://docs.vapor.codes/basics/environment/?h=envir#process-variables) for all the information about environment variables.

Comment: If someone is deploying to Heroku (like me) just use `Environment.get("DYNO") == "web.1"`